# Можно ли сделать мониторинг сообщений ВКонтакте через python?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Можно ли логгировать входящие сообщения ВКонтакте через python с помощью vk_api, если да то каким методом, в документации ничего не нашёл

Comment: Входящие куда? Кому?

Comment: Входящие пользователю, допустим я хочу принимать сообщения от других пользователей себе, как это можно провернуть через vk_api

Comment: На шел на одном сайте - >Можно использовать `messages.get` с параметром `{"out": 0}` который вернёт список объект личных сообщений, в котором есть параметр `user_id` - список людей (их id), которые когда либо писали сообщения (и им, соответственно, можно отправлять). Далее через `users.get` получить id пользователя, и циклом искать совпадение. Сам не понял как использовать, если поймете, ответьте пж)

Answer (score 0):

В Базе Данных можно создать папку, в которой будут хранится все сообщения пользователей:

От Пользователя и От Сообщества.

Пример кода:

```
import os

#Код

msg_mon = event.text #Сообщение мониторинга
user_id = event.user_id #id пользователя
if event.from_user:
    user_get = vk.users.get(user_ids=(user_id)) #Получение данных пользователя .1
    user_get = user_get[0] #Получение данных пользователя .2
    first_name = user_get["first_name"] #Имя
    last_name = user_get["last_name"] #Фамилия
    full_name = f"{first_name} {last_name}" #Полностью

file = "Data Base/Message Monitoring/"+str(user_id)+".расширение" #Проверка файла с сообщениями
check_file = os.path.exists(file)

if check_file == False: #Если отсутсвует
    with open(file, "w") as f: #Создаём файл
        text1 = f"Пользователь: {full_name} ({user_id})\nСообщения:\n\n" #Тексты .1
        if event.from_user:
            text2 = f"{user_name}: {msg_mon}" #Тексты .2 если пользователь
        if event.from_me:
            text2 = f"Сообщество: {msg_mon}" #Тексты .2 если сообщество
        f.write(text1)
        f.write(text2)
if check_file == True: #Если существует
    with open(file, "a") as f: #Редактируем файл
        if event.from_user:
            text = f"{user_name}: {msg_mon}" #Тексты .2 если пользователь
        if event.from_me:
            text = f"Сообщество: {msg_mon}" #Тексты .2 если сообщество
        f.write(text)
```